# Unable to integrated Azure-AD with Next-auth

Tags: next.js, azure-active-directory, next-auth

Has anyone been able to integrate Next-Auth with Azure AD.

I did everything as per the docs but except Azure AD - every other provider works seamlessly with Next Auth.

Get the error:

```
 [next-auth][error][SIGNIN_OAUTH_ERROR] 
https://next-auth.js.org/errors#signin_oauth_error read ECONNRESET {
  error: {
    message: 'read ECONNRESET',
    stack: 'Error: read ECONNRESET\n' +
      '    at TLSWrap.onStreamRead (internal/stream_base_commons.js:209:20)',
    name: 'Error'
  },
  providerId: 'azure-ad',
  message: 'read ECONNRESET'
}
```

Followed this: https://next-auth.js.org/providers/azure-ad

Added that provider in with proper details in their demo project: https://github.com/nextauthjs/next-auth-example

Has anyone been able to get this running?

Comment: I was able to make it work without any errors. Make sure to select "Web" for Authentication Platform instead of "Single-page application" on Azure AD configuration page. The reason is the authentication mechanism is handled by backend on the next-auth-example application.